# Stack overflow on subroutine call only when compiled with Intel Visual Fortran and fine when compiled by Compaq Visual Fortran

Tags: arguments, fortran, intel-fortran

Using identical source files for a Fortran .dll I can compile them with Compaq Visual Fortran 6.6C or Intel Visual Fortran 12.1.3.300 (IA-32). The problem is that the execution fails on the Intel binary, but works well with Compaq. I am compiling 32-bit on a Windows 7 64-bit system. The .dll calling driver is written in `C#`.

The failure message comes from the dreaded [`_chkstk()`](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/v-s/debug/article.php/c19241/Adventures-with-chkstk.htm) call when an internal subroutine is called (called from the .dll entry routine). (SO answer on [`chkstk()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9210322/380384))

The procedure in question is declared as (pardon the fixed file format)

```
  SUBROUTINE SRF(den, crpm, icrpm, inose, qeff, rev,  
 &               qqmax, lvtyp1, lvtyp2, avespd, fridry, luin,  
 &               luout, lurtpo, ludiag, ndiag, n, nzdepth, 
 &               unit, unito, ier)

  INTEGER*4 lvtyp1, lvtyp2, luin, luout, lurtpo, ludiag, ndiag, n, 
 &          ncp, inose, icrpm, ier, nzdepth
  REAL*8    den, crpm, qeff, rev, qqmax, avespd, fridry           
  CHARACTER*2  unit, unito
```

and called like this:

```
      CALL SRF(den, crpm(i), i, inose, qeff(i), rev(i),  
 &             qqmax(i), lvtyp1, lvtyp2, avespd, fridry, 
 &             luin, luout, lurtpo, ludiag, ndiag, n, nzdepth,  
 &             unit, unito, ier)
```

with similar variable specifications except for `crpm`, `qeff`, `rev` and `qqmax` are arrays of which only the `i-th` elements is used for each `SRF()` call.

I understand possible stack issues if the arguments are more than `8kb` in size, but in this case we have `7 x real(64) + 11 x int(32) + 2 x 2 x char(8) = 832 bits` only in passed arguments.

I have worked really hard to move arguments (especially arrays) into a module, but I keep getting the same error

[image: error].

The dissasembly from the **Intel** .dll is

[image: intel]

The dissasembly from the **Compaq** .dll is

[image: compaq]

Can anyone offer any suggestions on what is causing the SO, or how to debug it?

PS. I have increased the reserved stack space to hundreds of `Mb` and the problem persists. I have tried skipping the `chkstk()` call in the dissasembler but in crashes the program. The stack check starts from address `0x354000` and iterates down to `0x2D2000` where it crashes accessing a guard page. The stack bottom address is `0x282000`.

Comment: What compiler options are you using in each case? Try compiling will all the warning error flags you can think of enabled. As a first step I tend to use `-std -check all -Warn all,nodec,interfaces,declarations -gen_interfaces -g -C -traceback -fpe0 -fp-stack-check` with ifort.

Comment: I expect you've spotted your own arithmetic mistake by now, but your total of 832 bytes should be 832 bits.  It's not always the case, either, that each character is represented by one byte: this tends to vary with compiler and platform.  With an up to date compiler the size of the various 'storage units' are available as constants defined in ISO_FORTRAN_ENV intrinsic module.

Comment: Both comments above give me something to work with. I will investigate more. It is possible there is a stack corruption that `CVF` is not catching and somehow blows over it. There is a lot going on in the code as many developers have touched it since the 80's when it was first written.

Comment: As an update none of the tricks and changes I have tried so far have gotten me any closer to a resolution. I have reduced the number and size of parameters down to like 8 scalars and the problem persist.

Comment: `_chkstk()` checks for enough stack space for local variables, not for arguments (they are already in the stack). Do you by and chance have large arrays local to the subroutine? Intel Fortran doesn't do heap allocation of local arrays by default.

Comment: Is it possible to post the entire subroutine `SRF`?

Comment: I cannot post `SRF` (it contains proprietary information), I will look into local variable storage. BTW how do you turn on heap storage for locals. I tried with `Fortran/Optimization/Heap Arrays=0` option but it made no difference.

Comment: It may help to determine on which instruction the stack overflows.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: As soon as I step into the function `SRF` it falls into `_chkstk()` and fails. None of the statements inside the function are hit upon.

Comment: Here is a related post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12916176/380384

Comment: Very long shot here given the question age, but have you found the solution to this? I have **precisely** the very same problem as you described. @hanspassant maybe? This question was ultimaltely left unanswered...

Comment: @CTZStef - Actually I did. There was a bug in the code beforehand that overfilled the stack. When I switched arrays from stack allocated to heal allocated and made them allocatable it solved the problem.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou ok yeah, makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't at the function call where the stack overflow occurred.

Earlier in the code, there were some global matrices initialized and they were placed in the stack and due to a bug in the code, they were still in scope and had already *almost* filled the stack. When the function call happened, the compiler tried to store the return address to the stack and it crashed the program.

The solution was to make the global matrices `allocatable` and also made sure the "Heap Arrays" option was set at an appropriate value.

Quite the rabbit hole this was, when it was 100% my buggy code the caused the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You are shooting the messenger.  The Compaq generated code *also* calls _chkstk(), the difference is that it inlined it.  A common optimization.  The key difference between the two snippets is:

```
 mov eax, 0D3668h
```

vs

```
 sub esp, 233E4h
```

The values you see used here are the amount of stack space required by the function.  The Intel code requires 0xd3668 bytes = 865869 bytes.  The Compaq code requires 0x233e4 = 144356.  Big difference.  In both cases that's rather a large amount but the Intel one is getting critical, a program normally has a one megabyte stack.  Gobbling up 0.86 megabytes of it is pushing it very close, nest a couple of functions calls and you're looking at this site's name.

What you need to find out, I can't help because it is not in your snippet, is why the Intel generated function needs so much space for its local variables.  Workarounds are to use the free store to find space for large arrays.  Or use the linker's /STACK option to ask for more stack space (guessing at the option name).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you elaborate on _use the free store_ to find space? There are a lot of computations that happen in this array, filling an array of 18,000,000 elements of `REAL*8`.

Comment: I'm pretty old but not quite old enough.  Look at the ALLOCATE and DEALLOCATE statements in your favorite Fortran reference.

Comment: These arrays are allocated in VBA and passed to the Fortran `.dll`. They are not allocated in Fortran, so I cannot use allocatable arrays. The posting has been very helpful though, as I am still looking for an answer here.