# gfortran for dummies: What does mcmodel=medium do exactly?

Tags: memory-management, fortran, x86-64, gfortran

I have some code that is giving me relocation errors when compiling, below is an example which illustrates the problem:

```
  program main
  common/baz/a,b,c
  real a,b,c
  b = 0.0
  call foo()
  print*, b
  end

  subroutine foo()
  common/baz/a,b,c
  real a,b,c

  integer, parameter :: nx = 450
  integer, parameter :: ny = 144
  integer, parameter :: nz = 144
  integer, parameter :: nf = 23*3
  real :: bar(nf,nx*ny*nz)

  !real, allocatable,dimension(:,:) :: bar
  !allocate(bar(nf,nx*ny*nz))

  bar = 1.0
  b = bar(12,32*138*42)

  return
  end
```

Compiling this with `gfortran -O3 -g -o test test.f`, I get the following error:

```
relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `baz_' defined in COMMON section in /tmp/ccIkj6tt.o
```

But it works if I use `gfortran -O3 -mcmodel=medium -g -o test test.f`.  Also note that it works if I make the array allocatable and allocate it within the subroutine.

My question is what exactly does `-mcmodel=medium` do?  I was under the impression that the two versions of the code (the one with `allocatable` arrays and the one without) were more or less equivalent ...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since `bar` is quite large the compiler generates static allocation instead of automatic allocation on the stack. Static arrays are created with the `.comm` assembly directive which creates an allocation in the so-called COMMON section. Symbols from that section are gathered, same-named symbols are merged (reduced to one symbol request with size equal to the largest size requested) and then what is rest is mapped to the BSS (uninitialised data) section in most executable formats. With ELF executables the `.bss` section is located in the data segment, just before the data segment part of the heap (there is another heap part managed by anonymous memory mappings which does not reside in the data segment).

With the `small` memory model 32-bit addressing instructions are used to address symbols on x86_64. This makes code smaller and also faster. Some assembly output when using `small` memory model:

```
movl    $bar.1535, %ebx    <---- Instruction length saving
...
movl    %eax, baz_+4(%rip) <---- Problem!!
...
.local  bar.1535
.comm   bar.1535,2575411200,32
...
.comm   baz_,12,16
```

This uses a 32-bit move instruction (5 bytes long) to put the value of the `bar.1535` symbol (this value equals to the address of the symbol location) into the lower 32 bits of the `RBX` register (the upper 32 bits get zeroed). The `bar.1535` symbol itself is allocated using the `.comm` directive. Memory for the `baz` COMMON block is allocated afterwards. Because `bar.1535` is very large, `baz_` ends up more than 2 GiB from the start of the `.bss` section. This poses a problem in the second `movl` instruction since a non-32bit (signed) offset from `RIP` should be used to address the `b` variable where the value of `EAX` has to be moved into. This is only detected during link time. The assembler itself does not know the appropriate offset since it doesn't know what the value of the instruction pointer (`RIP`) would be (it depends on the absolute virtual address where the code is loaded and this is determined by the linker), so it simply puts an offset of `0` and then creates a relocation request of type `R_X86_64_PC32`. It instructs the linker to patch the value of `0` with the real offset value. But it cannot do that since the offset value would not fit inside a signed 32-bit integer and hence bails out.

With the `medium` memory model in place things look like this:

```
movabsq $bar.1535, %r10
...
movl    %eax, baz_+4(%rip)
...
.local  bar.1535
.largecomm      bar.1535,2575411200,32
...
.comm   baz_,12,16
```

First a 64-bit immediate move instruction (10 bytes long) is used to put the 64-bit value which represents the address of `bar.1535` into register `R10`. Memory for the `bar.1535` symbol is allocated using the `.largecomm` directive and thus it ends in the `.lbss` section of the ELF exectuable. `.lbss` is used to store symbols which might not fit in the first 2 GiB (and hence should not be addressed using 32-bit instructions or RIP-relative addressing), while smaller things go to `.bss` (`baz_` is still allocated using `.comm` and not `.largecomm`). Since the `.lbss` section is placed after the `.bss` section in the ELF linker script, `baz_` would not end up being inaccessible using 32-bit RIP-related addressing.

All addressing modes are described in the [System V ABI: AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf). It is a heavy technical reading but a must read for anybody who really wants to understand how 64-bit code works on most x86_64 Unixes.

When an `ALLOCATABLE` array is used instead, `gfortran` allocates heap memory (most likely implemented as an anonymous memory map given the large size of the allocation):

```
movl    $2575411200, %edi
...
call    malloc
movq    %rax, %rdi
```

This is basically `RDI = malloc(2575411200)`. From then on elements of `bar` are accessed by using positive offsets from the value stored in `RDI`:

```
movl    51190040(%rdi), %eax
movl    %eax, baz_+4(%rip)
```

For locations that are more than 2 GiB from the start of `bar`, a more elaborate method is used. E.g. to implement `b = bar(12,144*144*450)` `gfortran` emits:

```
; Some computations that leave the offset in RAX
movl    (%rdi,%rax), %eax
movl    %eax, baz_+4(%rip)
```

This code is not affected by the memory model since nothing is assumed about the address where the dynamic allocation would be made. Also, since the array is not passed around, no descriptor is being built. If you add another function that takes an assumed-shaped array and pass `bar` to it, a descriptor for `bar` is created as an automatic variable (i.e. on the stack of `foo`). If the array is made static with the `SAVE` attribute, the descriptor is placed in the `.bss` section:

```
movl    $bar.1580, %edi
...
; RAX still holds the address of the allocated memory as returned by malloc
; Computations, computations
movl    -232(%rax,%rdx,4), %eax
movl    %eax, baz_+4(%rip)
```

The first move prepares the argument of a function call (in my sample case `call boo(bar)` where `boo` has an interface that declares it as taking an assumed-shape array). It moves the address of the array descriptor of `bar` into `EDI`. This is a 32-bit immediate move so the descriptor is expected to be in the first 2 GiB. Indeed, it is allocated in the `.bss` in both `small` and `medium` memory models like this:

```
.local  bar.1580
.comm   bar.1580,72,32
```

Comment: This is a very nice explanation.  Thanks.  This gives me a good start to looking much deeper into a bunch of this stuff (which is what I was looking for).

Comment: @mgilson, just for completeness of the answer, I have added also explanations to what happens when `bar` is passed by descriptor to another subroutine.

Answer (score 10):

No, large static arrays (as your `bar`) may exceed the limit if you do not use `-mcmodel=medium`. But allocatables are better of course. For allocatables only the array descriptor must fit into 2 GB, not the whole array.

From GCC reference:

```
-mcmodel=small
Generate code for the small code model: the program and its symbols must be linked in the lower 2 GB of the address space. Pointers are 64 bits. Programs can be statically or dynamically linked. This is the default code model. 
-mcmodel=kernel
Generate code for the kernel code model. The kernel runs in the negative 2 GB of the address space. This model has to be used for Linux kernel code. 
-mcmodel=medium
Generate code for the medium model: The program is linked in the lower 2 GB of the address space but symbols can be located anywhere in the address space. Programs can be statically or dynamically linked, but building of shared libraries are not supported with the medium model. 
-mcmodel=large
Generate code for the large model: This model makes no assumptions about addresses and sizes of sections. Currently GCC does not implement this model.
```

Comment: I suppose, maybe the question is what is the difference between a "static array" and an "allocatable array"?  My impression was that they would be allocated from the heap in both cases (although I should admit that I'm talking about things which I don't have much knowledge about)

Comment: I just edited the answer when you wrote. Allocatables have a descriptor (pointer with additional data) and only this must fit into 2 GB. Static array is completely in the static segment just as any other static variable.

Comment: (Maybe there is just a pointer to the descriptor in the static segment, but it does not change the difference.)

Comment: If I understand correctly the 2GB limit for static arrays no longer applies for `mcmodel=small`. Is this correct?

Comment: I think it does apply, it does not apply with medium and large.

Comment: @VladimirF I have a similar problem 'failed to convert GOTPCREL relocation; relink with --no-relax'. I have tried --no-relax and -mcmodel=large but the error seems to persist. What could be a possible solution to this? Kindly help.

Comment: @NealTitusThomas I do not know this error message. I suggest asking a new question.

Comment: @VladimirF Unfortunately, I have run out of my quota of questions. I have figured out that the size of my array is too large and most solutions to this problem is to either use the -mcmodel=medium/large or use allocatable arrays. I tried the former and I am not sure how to do the later as I am very new to fortran and the code that I am working on is some old legacy code.

Comment: @NealTitusThomas In that case you should first follow https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th