# `relocation truncated to fit` errors when compiling Daomaster in Stetson

Tags: fortran, iraf

I'm interested in using the Stetson package, but I'm having trouble with the "daomaster" executable. All the other executables have been successfully produced, but the compiler returns several error messages related to "daomaster". Could you provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? This is the makefile and what is displayed in the terminal.

```
    F77 = gfortran
    FFLAGS = -c -O2 -mcmodel=medium -fd-lines-as-comments 
    LFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -Wsurprising -defsym,mem_=0 -fbounds-check 
    HOSTLIBS = -lm 
    IMFORT = $(HOME)/0Hamid/Software/Iraf/iraf-2.17/unix/bin.linux64/libf2c.a $(HOME)/0Hamid/Software/Iraf/iraf-2.17/bin.linux64/libimfort.a $(HOME)/0Hamid/Software/Iraf/iraf-2.17/bin.linux64/libsys.a $(HOME)/0Hamid/Software/Iraf/iraf-2.17/bin.linux64/libvops.a $(HOME)/0Hamid/Software/Iraf/iraf-2.17/unix/bin.linux64/libos.a
    FITLIB = -lcfitsio
    
    INSTALL_TO = $(HOME)/bin
    EXECUTABLES = daophot allstar daomaster daomatch montage2 allframe daogrow #daospec
    
    # RULES:
    .SUFFIXES: .o .f
    .f.o:
        $(F77) $(FFLAGS) $<
    
    all: $(EXECUTABLES)
    
    install: all
        cp $(EXECUTABLES) $(INSTALL_TO)
        
    .PHONY : clean
    clean:
        rm -f $(EXECUTABLES)
        rm -f *.o
    
    daophot: daophot.o pckpsf.o find.o fotometry.o \
            psf.o peak.o nstar.o fudge.o addstar.o substar.o \
            group.o sort.o lnxsubs.o fitsubs.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o
        $(F77) $(LFLAGS) -o daophot daophot.o pckpsf.o find.o fotometry.o \
            psf.o peak.o nstar.o fudge.o addstar.o substar.o \
            group.o sort.o lnxsubs.o fitsubs.o \
        iosubs.o mathsubs.o \
            $(IMFORT) $(HOSTLIBS) $(FITLIB)
    
    allstar: allstar.o allstsubs.o lnxsubs.o \
        iosubs.o mathsubs.o fitsubs.o
        $(F77) $(LFLAGS) -o allstar allstar.o allstsubs.o \
        lnxsubs.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o fitsubs.o \
        $(IMFORT) $(HOSTLIBS) $(FITLIB)
    
    daomaster: daomaster.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o lnxsubs.o dummysm.o 
        $(F77) $(LFLAGS) -o daomaster daomaster.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o lnxsubs.o dummysm.o
    
    daomatch: daomatch.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o lnxsubs.o
        $(F77) $(LFLAGS) -o daomatch daomatch.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o lnxsubs.o
    
    montage2: montage2.o mathsubs.o iosubs.o lnxsubs.o fitsubs.o
        $(F77) $(LFLAGS) -o montage2 montage2.o mathsubs.o iosubs.o lnxsubs.o fitsubs.o \
            $(HOSTLIBS) $(IMFORT) $(FITLIB)
    
    allframe: allframe.o fitsubs.o lnxsubs.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o
        $(F77) $(LFLAGS) -o allframe allframe.o fitsubs.o \
        lnxsubs.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o \
            $(IMFORT) $(HOSTLIBS) $(FITLIB)
    
    # to compile tdaogrow, added mcmodel on FFLAGS, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html
    daogrow: daogrow.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o lnxsubs.o
        $(F77) $(LFLAGS) -o daogrow daogrow.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o lnxsubs.o
    
    # daospec source file(s) missing, commented out ...
    #daospec: daospec.o lnxsubs.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o fitsubs.o
    #   $(F77) $(LFLAGS) -o daospec daospec.o lnxsubs.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o fitsubs.o \
        $(IMFORT) $(HOSTLIBS) $(FITLIB)  -Bstatic -L/usr/local/lib -lplotsub -ldevices -lutils -Bdynamic /usr/X11R6/lib/libX11.a
```

The output:

```
f77 -c -O2 -mcmodel=medium -fd-lines-as-comments    daophot.f   -o daophot
daophot.f:396:29:

             CALL DUMP (WORK, NCOL, NROW, INDEX)
                             1
Warning: Rank mismatch in argument ‘ncol’ at (1) (scalar and rank-1) [-Wargument-mismatch]
f77 -c -O2 -mcmodel=medium -fd-lines-as-comments    allstar.f   -o allstar
gfortran -c -O2 -mcmodel=medium -fd-lines-as-comments  daomaster.f
gfortran -c -O2 -mcmodel=medium -fd-lines-as-comments  iosubs.f
gfortran -c -O2 -mcmodel=medium -fd-lines-as-comments  mathsubs.f
gfortran -c -O2 -mcmodel=medium -fd-lines-as-comments  lnxsubs.f
gfortran -c -O2 -mcmodel=medium -fd-lines-as-comments  dummysm.f
gfortran -O2 -Wall -Wsurprising -defsym,mem_=0 -fbounds-check  -o daomaster daomaster.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o lnxsubs.o dummysm.o
daomaster.o: in function `master_':
daomaster.f:(.text+0x2ae6): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
daomaster.f:(.text+0x872c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
iosubs.o: in function `rdhead_':
iosubs.f:(.text+0x2837): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `head3_' defined in COMMON section in iosubs.o
iosubs.f:(.text+0x283e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `head3_' defined in COMMON section in iosubs.o
iosubs.f:(.text+0x2845): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `head3_' defined in COMMON section in iosubs.o
iosubs.f:(.text+0x284c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `head3_' defined in COMMON section in iosubs.o
iosubs.f:(.text+0x2853): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `head3_' defined in COMMON section in iosubs.o
iosubs.f:(.text+0x2af1): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `head3_' defined in COMMON section in iosubs.o
iosubs.o: in function `wrhead_':
iosubs.f:(.text+0x35fa): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `head3_' defined in COMMON section in iosubs.o
iosubs.f:(.text+0x3639): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `head3_' defined in COMMON section in iosubs.o
mathsubs.o: in function `daoran_':
mathsubs.f:(.text+0x4de3): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:28: daomaster] Error 1
```

I also followed the recommendations in this [link](https://www.astrobetter.com/wiki/DAOphot). But I still did not get the result.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687170/relocation-truncated-to-fit-error-in-fortran-with-large-arrays It is always best to start by searching the error message. `medium` is already used in the Makefile but try to put it everywhere. If it does not help, try `large`.

Comment: `large` solved it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good to know, I closed it as a duplicate pointing to those answers where the details are described.