# Clarification required on gcc option -mcmodel=medium

Tags: powerpc, compiler-options, gcc4, gcc8

While compiling one of our dependent tool, a long list relocation error is showing up while linking:

```
SomeLibrary.a(SomeObject.o)(.text._bla_bla_bla): error: relocation overflow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
cook: command g++: exit status 1
```

The dependent tool is being compiled on `gcc-8.x` and our tool is compiled on `gcc-4.x`.

This problem is specifically showing up on IBM `PowerPC` platform, where `RHEL` is compiling fine.

We are being suggested to use `-mcmodel=medium` while compiling our code.

Could not find much help online. Any specific purpose of using this option?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916176/gfortran-for-dummies-what-does-mcmodel-medium-do-exactly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gfortran for dummies: What does mcmodel=medium do exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916176/gfortran-for-dummies-what-does-mcmodel-medium-do-exactly)

Comment: Looking for PowerPC specific solution. Maybe some more sophistication? Not sure.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with PowerPC, but I assume the answer would be the same. By using -mcmodel=medium you get larger sections at the cost of some instruction density?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "more sophistication"

Comment: The Power  and gcc toolchain developers try to make all options look the same. Does mcmodel=medium work for you?