# Optimal way to create once, then frequently access to a large array in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I have a scientific simulation in Fortran. In it, I need to calculate a large array (say 10^5 elements, a size known / that can be preset when writing the code) "once" around the beginning, and then this array will need to be shared / accessed / read into a lot of times (basically at each step, so possibly millions of times).

What is the recommended way of sharing such an array with other subroutines ? Given that I want the code creating the large array to be its own entity.

Say there is case 1, where :

- The array needs to be generated at runtime, and actually will be generated once per run of the Monte-Carlo (so it will actually be generated more than once during the simulation). The size of the array can be considered fixed and known / preset when writing the code.
- a few different subroutines will need access to the array at each timestep (say ~10^6 timesteps per run)
- each of them will read only one element at a time
- each of them will read into it almost sequentially (and almost at the same points)

There is case 2, where :

- The array needs to be generated at runtime, and will actually be generated only once (it will be the same for all runs of the Monte-Carlo)
- The array will actually be noticeably smaller. The size of the array can be considered fixed and known / preset when writing the code.
- It will only be used in one subroutine, but it will need to be almost read entirely every time (ie at every timestep).

Finally there is case 3, which is exactly as case 2, except the array could be physically preset / written in code as a data statement.

What would be the best practice in each case, and to optimize speed / minimize possible runtime penalties ?

Edit : this is the solution I have in place for now. Have a module of the form

```
    module big_array
    parameter (nbigarray=10**5)
    
    real my_by_array(nbigarray)
    
    contains
    
      subroutine init_big_array(arglist)
    
      *[here some code populating / creating *my_big_array*]*

      return
      end
    
    end module
```

run `init_big_array` once at the start of the program and use the module wherever `my_big_array` is needed.

Comment: This is quite broad. There are many ways how software can be structured. It depends on the rest of the design of the software as well. From what I read in your cases it would make sense to place the array into a module and allocate it when needed at the start of the program.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirFГероямслава. Would you be kind enough to provide an explicit example ?

Comment: Pass it as an argument, you will thank yourself in the long run - keep your subroutines `Pure` wherever possible. Only begin to worry about speed when the *working* code turns out not to be fast enough for your needs. And if you need to optimise a well structured, easy to read and understand code will very much help you in that exercise - especially being able to work on small, individual parts independently.

Comment: Also note 10^5 elements is not that big on a modern machine, unless each of those elements is some reasonably large derived type. In fact there's a good possibility it will fit in cache. Are these the "positions" in the MC simulation?

Comment: Place its declaration with an  `ALLOCATABLE` attribute in a `MODULE`, and then `USE` that module wherever you need access to array.  For bonus points, the module can contain init() and destroy() procedure for memory management.

Comment: @steve I have put an example of a module form as previously suggested. What would be the point of the `allocatale` attribute here ? Notice I do know the size beforehand (I understand the point if size itself was to be determined at runtime)

Comment: The `allocatable` attribute allows one to allocate an array of the desired.

Comment: Putting the array in a module and use the module is a simple solution and it will work, and this is overall fine to quickly write a test/small code just for you. But you should understand that this is *generally* not a good design for code maintenance and extensibilty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an intro to dynamic memory management that allows one to expose `array` to subprograms.

```
module foo

   implicit none  ! Always include this statement
   !
   ! Make everything private and only expose those entities
   ! that are needed.
   !
   private
   public array, init_array, destroy_array

   integer, allocatable :: array(:)

   contains
      !
      ! Destroy array
      !
      subroutine destroy_array
         if (allocated(array)) then
            deallocate(array)
         end if   
      end subroutine

      subroutine init_array(n)
         integer, intent(in) :: n
         if (n < 0) then
            !
            ! Could implement a fallback.  Perhaps,
            ! allocate a zero-sized array.
            !
            write(*,'(A)') 'init_array: memory allocation issue'
            stop
         end if
         !
         ! Check if array is allocated and the requested size
         ! differs from the current allocated size.
         !
         if (allocated(array)) then
            if (size(array) /= n) then
               call destroy_array
               allocate(array(n))
            end if
         else
            allocate(array(n))
         end if   
      end subroutine
end module foo

program main
   use foo, only : array, init_array
   implicit none
   integer m
   !
   ! Perhaps, "read(*,*) m" to allow user to size
   ! memory appropriately.
   !
   m = 100

   call init_array(m)
   call bar
end program

subroutine bar
   use foo, only : array
   implicit none
   if (allocated(array) then
      print *, size(array)
   else
      write(*,'(A)') 'whoops'
   end if
end subroutine bar
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you agree that if m is fixed and known beforehand, there is no benefit from using an allocatable array ?

Comment: Yes, of course.  The module would then include only the declaration statement `integer array(100)`, and you `USE` it as essentially a `COMMON` statement.

Comment: @ParkerLewis There's little -if any at all- benefit to use a static arrays either. Moreover, when it comes to very large arrays, the usual practice nowadays is to allocate them. I've seen compiler bugs with very large static arrays, because this is something that is rarely used and hence debugged.

Comment: @ParkerLewis Usually with the default `mcmodel=small` the limit is 2GB for all code + static data. You can use `mcmodel=medium` but really for large arrays you're better of using allocatables. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916176/gfortran-for-dummies-what-does-mcmodel-medium-do-exactly for details.